# Using Atomic and infinite loop to do synchronisation in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, atomic, synchronized

Consider the following code

```
static AtomicBoolean initialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);
static AtomicBoolean initStarted= new AtomicBoolean(false);

public static void init() {
    if (!initialized.get() && !initStarted.getAndSet(true)) {
        doInitialization();
        initialized.set(true);
    }
    // start waiting
    while (!initialized.get());
    // finished waiting
    doMoreStuff();
}
```

It achieves what I want to make sure `doMoreStuff()` is not called until `doInitialization()` has completed and only the very first thread should call `doInitialization()`.

My question is, how does this compare to using `synchronized` block to the whole `init()` method?

As I see AtomicReference also use infinite loop (a.k.a busy waiting) to waste CPU cycle to do update (see `AtomicReference#getAndUpdate()`), so may be it is not so bad to do the same here as a synchronisation method?

If infinite loop is so bad (e.g. wasting CPU cycle) then why don't AtomicReference use `synchronized` to stop or wake up threads?

Comment: @Thilo Yes, as seen in my code. An infinite loop with break condition.

Comment: `if (!initialized.get() && !updating.getAndSet(true))` ... I don't like this, because I think it might allow two threads to both enter a critical section, which should be possible in terms of what you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ummm, how? Both are atomic functions.

Comment: @user1589188 Yes but wouldn't each call require a single bytecode instruction?  Then how can that `if` check be completely atomic?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right. I should not use that then. Thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How about now, the if block will not reset the second AtomicBoolean now. So there is no way to reenter the block twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AtomicReference#getAndUpdate is not using busy waiting to block until an external condition has changed.

```
134        * Atomically sets to the given value and returns the old value.
135        *
136        * @param newValue the new value
137        * @return the previous value
138        */
139       public final V getAndSet(V newValue) {
140           while (true) {
141               V x = get();
142               if (compareAndSet(x, newValue))
143                   return x;
144           }
145       }
```

The loop is expected to run just once except in the case of contention.
The only way `compareAndSet` can fail is if another thread did the same thing at exactly the same time.

This is called "retry-loop" and should be executed only a very few number of times (approximately once).

Comment: Isnt this the exact reason why we want synchronisation? And AtomicReference chose to use "retry-loop" until done, instead of `synchronized` block.

Comment: This is also called "optimistic locking". Synchronization is "pessimistic locking". Unless you have a lot of contention, if you can easily and cheaply retry your update operation when (very rarely) required, the overhead of taking out a synchronization lock for every update "just in case" is not worth it.

Comment: Also note that the getters are completely lock-free and loop-free.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. So the question really is, how do you determine your task at hand is "optimistic" or "pessimistic" when facing thread contention?

Comment: If your `doInitialization` takes any amount of time, that `loop` could be busy waiting for a long time. Better to use a wait/notify pattern here. Or a Latch.

Comment: It seems like the "lazy loading singleton" pattern. There should be some tool packaged for that already.

Answer (score 2):

AtomicBoolean.getAndSet works if you only would like allow a single thread to access a specific block, just as you did, but I would not recommend to use it in a if-statement with other variables that might change, even though this case probably would have been safe. You while loop is however consuming 100% CPU while waiting, so I suggest that you use a CountDownLatch instead.

```
AtomicBoolean initialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);
CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);

public void init() throws InterruptedException {
    if (!initialized.getAndSet(true)) {
        doInitialization();
        lock.countDown();
    }
    // start waiting
    lock.await();
    // finished waiting
    doMoreStuff();
}
```